# VBA Vlookup with Match function

Tags: excel, vba

I have created the pivot table using VBA code and named it as Pivot1. All I'm looking is to set up a dynamic VBA Vlookup code as the row headers in the pivot may keep changing. 
I have used match function formula and I'm able to get the result when I apply this on the cell but unable to write a VBA code using this.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($D18,Pivot1!$A$4:$D$27,MATCH(E$17,Pivot1!$A$4:$E$4,0),0),0)
```

Please help me in adding this match function in this VBA code -

```
Range("E18").Activate

ActiveCell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1), Sheets("Pivot1").Range("A1:E50"), 2, 0)

ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
```

Comment: Wouldn't `GETPIVOTDATA` be more reliable? Or can you lookup off the data source of the pivot rather than off the pivot itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're stuck using Application.Match(), though GetPivotData from Mat's Mug's suggestion would seem more appropriate, then you would add that similar to your Application.VLookUp()... i would recommend using a with statement, so you don't have to keep retyping the same thing:

```
With Sheets("Pivot1") 
    ActiveCell.Value = Application.VLookup(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value, .Range("A4:D27"), Application.Match(ActiveCell.Offset(-1,0).Value, .Range("A4:E4"),0), 0)
End With
```

Comment: Guessed at the offsets a little as it appears you're on cell E18 when activating the macro, which uses D18 for the vlookup value and referencing E17 for the Match

Comment: Ha! Makes me wonder whether I should re-rename my account back to "Mat's Mug" =)

Comment: @MohammedSufiyan wonderful!  please mark as Answered (the checkmark next to the voting on the answer) so this can be closed!